# ScalaTest: assert blocking statement

Tags: scala, concurrency, future, reactive-programming, scalatest

I'm using some code with `blocking` statement:

```
blocking {
    Thread.sleep(10*1000)
}
```

Is there a way to assert that this `blocking` statement is given? Or in other words: Can I write a test that fails if somebody removes the `blocking` statement?

**Update:** How to assert blocking when used in `Future`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try playing with [BlockContext](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.BlockContext).

You should get something like this:

```
var blocked = false // flag to detect blocking

val oldContext = BlockContext.current
val myContext = new BlockContext {
  override def blockOn[T](thunk: =>T)(implicit permission: CanAwait): T = {
    blocked = true
    oldContext.blockOn(thunk)
  }
}

BlockContext.withBlockContext(myContext) {
  blocking {} // block (or not) here
}

assert(blocked) // verify that blocking happened
```

**Update on making it work if you want to test code wrapped in `Future` (comment follow-up)**

When you construct the `Future` it's factory method takes *block of code* (function) to execute **explicitly** and *execution context* **implicitly** (commonly `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`).

The *block of code* later will be scheduled to *execution context* and will be runned in one of it's threads.

Now, if you simply wrap blocking piece of code into Future inside code block passed to `BlockContext.withBlockContext`, like you suggest in comment:

```
BlockContext.withBlockContext(myContext) {
  Future {
    blocking { Thread.sleep(100) }
  }
}
```

... this will not work since your current thread will only do `Future` construction and actual code passed to `Future` will be executed in thread from relevant execution context (`BlockContext.withBlockContext` detects `blocking`s in current thread).

Having that said, I can suggest you to do one of 3 things:

1. Do not wrap code you want to test into Future. If you want to test whether piece of code uses `blocking` or not - just do that.
   Write a function and test it, you can pass it to `Future` in production.
2. Lets assume that for some reason you can't avoid creating Future in your test. In this case you'll have to tamper with execution context that is used when constucting future.
   This code sample demonstrates how one could do that (reuse `blocked` and `myContext` from my original example):

```
// execution context that submits everything that is passed to it to global execution context
// it also wraps any work submited to it into block context that records blocks
implicit val ec = new ExecutionContext {
  override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = {
   ExecutionContext.Implicits.global execute new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        BlockContext.withBlockContext(myContext) {
          runnable.run()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  override def reportFailure(t: Throwable): Unit = {
    ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.reportFailure(t)
  }
}

// this future will use execution context defined above
val f = Future {
  blocking {} // block (or not) here
}
Await.ready(f, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)

assert(blocked)
```

3. If your `Future` gets created indirectly, for example, as a result calling some other function that you run in your test, then you'll have to somehow (possibly using dependency injection) drag your mocked execution context into wherever `Future` gets created and use it there to consruct it.

As you can see, the first option is the simpliest one and I suggest sticking to it if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! It works well unless I don't use `blocking{}` in `Future`s:
    `BlockContext.withBlockContext(myContext) {
      Future{blocking{Thread.sleep(100)}}
    }`
Do you have an idea how to solve it?